# Using MySQL JSON field to join on a table with custom fields

Tags: mysql, json, database

So I made this system to store custom objects with custom fields for an app that I'm developing. First I have object_def where I save the object definitions:

```
id   | name     | fields       
------------------------------------------------------------
101  | Group 1  | [{"name": "Title", "id": "AbCdE123"}, ...]
102  | Group 2  | [{"name": "Name", "id": "FgHiJ456"},  ...]
```

So we have ID (INT), name (VARCHAR) and fields (LONGTEXT). In fields are the object fields like this: `{id: string, type: string, name: string}[]`.

Now In the object table, I have this:

```
id      | object_def_id | object_values       
------------------------------------------------------------
235     | 101           | {"AbCdE123": "The Object", ... }
236     | 102           | {"FgHiJ456": "John Perez", ... }
```

Where object_values is a LONGTEXT also. With that system, I'm able to show the objects on a table in my app using JSON.parse().

Now I've learned that there is a JSON type in MySQL and I want it to use it to do queries and stuff (I'm really new to this).

I've changed the LONGTEXT to JSON and now I wanted to do a SELECT that show the results like this:

```
#Select objects in group 1:

id   | group    | Title      | ... | other_custom_field
-------------------------------------------------------
235  | Group 1  | The Object | ... | other_custom_value

#Select objects in group 2:

id   | group    | Name       | ... | other_custom_field
-------------------------------------------------------
236  | Group 2  | John Perez | ... | other_custom_value
```

Id, then group name (I can do this with INNER JOIN) and then all the custom fields with the respective values.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this (hopefully without changing my database structure)? I'm learning MySQL, SQL and databases as I go so I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using please

Comment: I'm using 5.7.25

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see with your design:

- Incorrect JSON format.

  ```
  [{name: 'Title', id: 'AbCdE123'}, ...]
  ```

  Should be:

  ```
  [{"name": "Title", "id": "AbCdE123"}, ...]
  ```

  You should use the JSON data type instead of LONGTEXT, because JSON will at least reject invalid JSON syntax.
- Setting column headings based on data. You can't do this in SQL. Columns and headings must be fixed at the time you prepare the query. You can't do an SQL query that changes its own column headings.
- Your object def has an array of attributes, but there's no way in MySQL 5.7 to loop over the "rows" of a JSON array. You'll need to use the [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) in MySQL 8.0.
- That will get you closer to being able to look up object values, but then you'll still have to pivot the data into the result set you describe, with one attribute in each column, as if the data had been stored in a traditional way. But SQL doesn't allow you to do dynamic pivoting in a single query. You can't make an SQL query that dynamically grows its own select-list based on the data it finds.

This all makes me wonder...

**Why don't you just store the data in the traditional way?**

Create a table per object type. Add one column to that table per attribute. That way you get column names. You get column types. You get column constraints — for example, how would you simulate `NOT NULL` or `UNIQUE` in your current system?

If you don't want to use SQL, then don't. There are alternatives, like document databases or key/value databases. But don't torture poor SQL by using it to implement an [Inner-Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: About the "Incorrect JSON format", I just typed fast and use `'` instead of `"`. Is actually well formatted in the database, because it's send throug an app using `JSON.stringify()`. And, also, if you read my question, I did change the data type from `LONGTEXT` to `JSON`.
Apart from that, thanks for the explanation!